# LCD Monitor image refresh terribly slow

Tags: display, lcd

My LCD monitor is about 4+ years old and has developed an issue where images fade in very slowly and fade out even more slowly.  This happened last week - there were no issues with the monitor before turning it on that day.  The monitor displays the same behavior even when not plugged into the computer - the built in screen saver does the same thing.  I've taken a video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKNQ1r7GE_c

So, is it broken for good, or is there some easy thing I could do to fix it?

Comment: It certainly looks like it's broken.

Comment: Probably no way to fix it either, unless you are some kind of electronics wiz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try would be to simply make sure that this is not a bizarre graphics card problem, if you can then plug another monitor in and see if it produces the same results.

Considering that the first "related" video on your page is a similar problem with the exact same type of monitor but with a lot of freaky lines instead of simply being slow updating ([Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyzi1CSa280&feature=related)) I would have a suspicion that the chip that controls the data being sent to the LCD panel has some kind of inherent problem.  Integrated circuits can fail in similar but amusingly different ways.

Those kind of integrated circuits are not easy to fix.  I think you should be looking for a new monitor.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Off to its final resting place the at recycling facility!